# Несколько тернарных условий для атрибута тега в Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Пытаюсь написать несколько тернарных условий для атрибута в одном теге. Но vue выдает ошибку.

Хочу получить такое:
`<a :href='(первое условие? действие, второе условие? действие, третье условие? действие): тут альтернатива если есть необходимость'>Ссылка</a>`

Что я делаю:
Есть переменная price=50;

`<a :href="[price<50?'/files/40.pdf': '',price==50?'/files/50.pdf': '']:'/files/60.pdf'" ></a>`

выдает ошибку на компиляцию и ругается на ":"

тогда сделал так
`<a :href="[price<50?'/files/40.pdf',price==50?'/files/50.pdf']:'/files/60.pdf'" ></a>`

такая же ошибка

тогда так
`<a :href="[price<50?'/files/40.pdf': '',price==50?'/files/50.pdf': '',price>50?'/files/60.pdf': ''] ></a>`

Тоже ошибка только на ","

не понимаю как это реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a :href="price < 50 ? '/files/40.pdf' : price === 50 ? '/files/50.pdf' : '/files/60.pdf'"></a>`

Если вы хотели такой результат. Вообще вложенные тернарники использовать это такое себе. К тому же, во vue есть computed

`<a :href="link"></a>`

```
computed: {
  link() {
    let fileName = 60;

    if (this.price < 50) {
      fileName = 40;
    }

    if (this.price === 50) {
      fileName = 50;
    }

    return `/files/${fileName}.pdf`;
  }
}
```

Comment: Да, это то что нужно. Спасибо за доп информацию